# iphone 4 splash screen size

Tags: ios, xcode5, splash-screen

Where in the attached image do I add my 640 x 96[image]0 splash screen?  My current 640 x 1136 splash screen works for iPhone 5.  In the attached image, I am using the 640 x 1136 for all the images but which ones do I need to replace for the iPhone 4?

Comment: Sorry.  Image attached.

Comment: R4 = 640x1136, 2x = 640x960, 1x = 320x480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 2x one. R4 is retina 4 inch, 1x is "classic", 2x is iPhone 4 and 4S.